# El menú desplegado no funciona en móvil

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un menú con varios niveles de navegación que hasta hace poco tiempo funcionaba correctamente, pero de un tiempo a esta parte ha dejado de funcionar correctamente en dispositivos móviles.

Cuando hago clic para desplegar alguna opción, éste se oculta y cuando lo abro de nuevo la opción seleccionada está desplegada.

Lo monté en su momento integrando *StickyNavbar.js*.

En la siguiente URL se puede ver su funcionamiento erróneo:

- https://strands.com/

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Has enlazado a la página que te falla, pero es preferible que nos indiques en la pregunta el código que falla para poder reproducirlo aquí sin necesidad de acceder a páginas externas.

Comment: Parece un problema de plugin de WordPress, yo buscaría otro plugin porque este parece antiguo y medio abandonado.

Comment: Hola @Juan, la verdad es que no estoy utilizando ningún plugin para gestionar este menú. Gracias de todos modos por tu aportación

Comment: Muchas gracias @OscarGarcia, pero la verdad es que no he podido aislar el error, por eso pedía ayuda de este modo. De todas formas, muchas gracias

Comment: Todo apunta a que el contenedor padre está recibiendo el evento de clic de los hijos por propagación del evento. Veo muchísimo código javascript a partir de la línea 324 del HTML generado. ¿Ese ese es el código javascript que usas para controlar la navegación de los menús? Es decir, ¿los `jQuery('.rv_button1').click(function(e)` son los manipuladores de eventos? Si es así, ¿podrías poner `e.stopPropagation();` además del `e.preventDefault();` al comienzo de cada manipulador?

Comment: Mirando el código fuente dela página con el problema que pones en la pregunta, se ve que que el plugin que se está usando es "Sticky Plugin v1.0.4 for jQuery". Su página  es http://stickyjs.com/ y en gitHub es el proyecto https://github.com/garand/sticky.    
Quizás el autor también pueda echar una mano, aunque insisto parece poco atendido (última actualización es de hace 4 años).

Comment: @Juan creo que no es necesario molestar al autor hasta que no se descarten otras soluciones más triviales. El corportamiento anómalo es muy claro: el evento "click"  está siendo atendido por dos elementos, y eso es debido a la forma en la que funciona la propagación de eventos. Primero probemos a evitar la propagación del evento a los elementos padre. Si eso no funciona entonces podréis consultar al desarrollador si así queréis.

Comment: No pretendo molestar al autor, doy información sobre el origen del script como  otro camino para buscar la solución.  Muchas veces, con los CMS, el código es bastante intrincado y difícil de seguir. Si el autor se molestó le pido disculpas.

Comment: @JuanmaGonzález , ¿pudiste probar lo que te sugerí?

Comment: @OscarGarcia aun no me he podido poner con esto, pero prometo mirarlo mañana sin falta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que estás sufriendo es por culpa de la propagación de eventos.

Al hacer "clic" en un elemento éste recibe el evento "click" durante la fase `Event.AT_TARGET`, pero los padres también lo recibirán durante la fase de propagación `Event.BUBBLING_PHASE`.

Puedes ver más sobre el estado de la propagación de eventos en el siguiente enlace:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/eventPhase

Aquí tienes la demostración de cómo el siguiente código se comporta como lo hace tu menú:

```js
const fases = {
  0: "Event.NONE",
  1: "Event.CAPTURING_PHASE",
  2: "Event.AT_TARGET (elemento)",
  3: "Event.BUBBLING_PHASE (propagación)",
};

$(".boton").click((e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(
    "Pulsado:",
    e.currentTarget.dataset.descripcion,
    "Fase:",
    fases[e.eventPhase]
  );
  $(e.currentTarget).children("ul").toggleClass('opened closed');
});
```

```css
.opened {
  display: block;
}

.closed {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="boton" data-descripcion="botón exterior">
  Menú principal
  <ul class="closed">
    <li>Hola 1</li>
    <li>
      <div class="boton" data-descripcion="botón interior">
        Submenú
        <ul class="closed">
          <li>Hola 2.1</li>
          <li>Hola 2.2</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Para solucionarlo basta con detener la propagación del evento a los elementos padre mediante [`Event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

Aquí tienes el código funcionando correctamente cancelando la propagación:

```js
const fases = {
  0: "Event.NONE",
  1: "Event.CAPTURING_PHASE",
  2: "Event.AT_TARGET (elemento)",
  3: "Event.BUBBLING_PHASE (propagación)",
};

$(".boton").click((e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log(
    "Pulsado:",
    e.currentTarget.dataset.descripcion,
    "Fase:",
    fases[e.eventPhase]
  );
  $(e.currentTarget).children("ul").toggleClass('opened closed');
});
```

```css
.opened {
  display: block;
}

.closed {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="boton" data-descripcion="botón exterior">
  Menú principal
  <ul class="closed">
    <li>Hola 1</li>
    <li>
      <div class="boton" data-descripcion="botón interior">
        Submenú
        <ul class="closed">
          <li>Hola 2.1</li>
          <li>Hola 2.2</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```